# How do I make my UI visible in UE4?

Tags: user-interface, unreal-engine4

I am trying to make my UI visible in the game but I'm not sure why it isn't. I have created it as an asset and modified it in the editor, then saved it only to see it is not visible. I have been trying for a few minutes now to make it visible but can't seem to do it. I also looked on the Internet and found one person that seemed to have the same problem as me but their solution did not work.

Basically, how do I make the UI I made in the editor visible in the game?

Product Version: `UE 4.12`

Answer (score 2):

So I had to add some stuff with my blueprints to draw the UI:

[image: Blueprint]

Basically I needed to make the `Class` the UI I had made inside the window, and then connect it to the Viewport.

**I cannot take credit for this answer though, as I had posted this question elsewhere too and got feedback: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/469420/how-do-i-make-my-ui-visible.html I am simply posting it in case anybody needs it.**

Comment: Also that if you want to remove a widget (i.e. make it invisible), call `Remove From Parent(widget)`.